# Timer format in primefaces extension

Tags: jsf, timer, date-formatting, primefaces-extensions

i tried to use primefaces extension timer...Let's say i set timeout is 172439221...

When I user format HH:mm:ss the timer cannot display 47:53:59...

So i try to create javascript function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function formatInterval(value) {
            var diffSeconds = value / 1000 % 60;
            var diffMinutes = value / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            var diffHours = value / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            var diffDays = value / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            if (diffDays > 0) {
                diffHours = diffHours + (diffDays * 24);
            }
            return Math.floor(diffHours) + ":" + Math.floor(diffMinutes) + ":" + Math.floor(diffSeconds);
        }</script>
```

and the timer like this

```
<pe:timer  
        update=":globalMessages createOrderButton" formatFunction="return formatInterval(value);"
        timeout="#{orderPendingBacking.calculateCountDownTimeNoLimit(pending.orderTime)}"  
        listener="#{orderPendingBacking.onTimeout()}"/>
```

But the output is like this [image]

The timer is wrong...it should be 47:53:59, and the timer didn't count down...

Please help me...thx

I change my javascript code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function formatInterval(value) {
            var diffSeconds = value / 1000 % 60;
            var diffMinutes = value / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            var diffHours = value / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            var diffDays = value / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            var days = Math.floor(diffDays);
            var hours = Math.floor(diffHours);
            if (days > 0) {
                hours = hours + (days * 24);
            }               
            return hours + ":" + Math.floor(diffMinutes) + ":" + Math.floor(diffSeconds); 
        }
</script>
```

Now the timer show correct value 47:53:59...But the timer still not count down

Comment: any client-side javascript errors? And please post version info to

Comment: for primefaces extension i use 3.0.0... when i inspect and see at console part, there is no error there

Comment: Do you use it with the right version of primefaces

Comment: my primefaces version is 5.3...when i use format HH:mm:ss the timer can count down only max HH is 24...

Comment: when i use format=HH:mm:ss the timer can count down...But when i using formatInterval function, I must refresh the page so the timer count down...I think ajax not work right?